# why does scanf() turn none into two float

Tags: c++, double, scanf

I'm a newbie on c++ and I am encountering some problems. The question to be solved is 
having 5 inputs, the inputs can include integers and the string "none", try to sum up the integers in the inputs and the result should be a double.
Here's what I have done: I put five inputs in the array and use scanf() to turn them into double, but when I enter none and use printf to see the array, I found out that it turns none into two float, does scanf has any restrictions on converting strings to double?

Here's the  code :

```
int main()
{
    double sc[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sc[i] = 3;
        scanf("%lf", &sc[i]);
        printf("%lf\n", sc[i]);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
34
34.000000
none
3.000000
3.000000
56
56.000000
89
89.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `scanf("%lf", &something)` will populate `something` if and only if the input is a valid floating point number. The string `none` is *not* such a valid number.

The reason you're getting two `3` values is probably because `nan` *is* a valid floating point number, so `scanf` finds the `n` and says "Hah, this will be a `nan`". But then it finds, much to its disappointment, the `o` and decides it's no longer valid.

But it has already read the `no` from the input stream. It then goes back and does the same thing with the `ne` <sup>(a)</sup>.

After that, you start giving it valid numbers again so it carries on.

---

If you want to be able to handle strings *and* numbers, you're going to have to use the least restrictive (string) and then decide. Something like this (though `scanf("%s")` is dangerous for real code, it's probably okay for classwork):

The following code does that and (as you should) checks the return value from `scanf/sscanf` to ensure it was correctly scanned:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    static char bigstring[1000];
    double sc[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sc[i] = 3;
        if (scanf("%s", bigstring) != 1) {
            puts("*** Could not get input");
            return 1;
        }

        if (strcmp("none", bigstring) == 0) {
            puts("Got 'none', converting to -999");
            sc[i] = -999;
        } else if (sscanf(bigstring, "%lf", &sc[i]) != 1) {
            printf("*** Could not convert input '%s' to float", bigstring);
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("Got %f\n", sc[i]);
        }
    }

    puts("\nThe five entered numbers were:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("   %lf\n", sc[i]);
    }
}
```

Running that works properly with basic test data:

```
pax:~$ printf "34\nnone\n56\n89\n111\n" | ./qq
Got 34.000000
Got 'none', converting to -999
Got 56.000000
Got 89.000000
Got 111.000000

The five entered numbers were:
   34.000000
   -999.000000
   56.000000
   89.000000
   111.000000
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Interestingly, it appears this only happens with real user input, not piping data through the program as per my `printf` statement.

The *ideal* behaviour, in my opinion, would be to leave the input stream pointing at the invalid data. In other words, unless the exact text is valid (like `nan`), the pointer should not move at all. However, there's a footnote in the C standard that allows for this behaviour if, for example, the input stream is not seekable:

> `fscanf` pushes back ***at most one input character*** onto the input stream.

So, while it may be able to back up further than that on a pipeline, that may not be the case when dealing with terminal input.

When I enter `x` as input, it appears it *does* push that back, because every single following array element is populated with `3`, meaning it's reading that `x` continuously. Anything starting with an `n` seems to consume that and the following character only.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but I still have two questions: the first one is "what does it mean by "sscanf(bigstring, "%lf, &sc[i] == 1"  and the second one is why aren't the sc array modified to doubles after the for loop, in other words , I expect when I enter 45 56 4 3 2, the sc should have 5 doubles, am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter, the `scanf` family return the number of items successfully scanned, so the comparison with `1` is meant to detect if it failed. If it worked, the `sc[i]` will be set and it will return one. I'm not sure why you think you don't have five doubles, I've modified the code slightly to make that clearer.